# Find the simplest $g(n)$ such that $f(n) \in \Theta(g(n))$

Tags: asymptotics

Let $f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i^{-1}$.
Would the simplest $g(n)$ be $1$?

If we let $g(n) = 1$, then for all $n > 1$, $g(n) \le f(n)$.
To construct an upper bound, observe that since $n$ is finite, $f(n) = C$ for some $C \in \mathbb R$. (Here $C$ is the $n$th harmonic number). Then by the Archimedean Property for real numbers, $\exists N \in \mathbb N$ such that $N > C$. So for all $n > N$, $f(n) \le N.g(n)$. Combining the two bounds we have that $f(n) \in \Theta(g(n))$.

Please let me know if what I have done is valid.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "simplest" function, but asymptotically $f(n)\sim \log n$.

Comment: The notion of "simplest" is not exactly clear to me either, this was the exact wording of the homework question, so I'm assuming "simplest" means only containing the dominating term, without any constants.

Comment: If my approach is wrong, I'd appreciate any feedback on where I went wrong.

Comment: Why is $n$ finite? You should have $f(n) \le k_2 g(n), n>n_0$. This is not the case for $g(n)=1.$

Comment: I think I meant to say the $n$th harmonic number is finite, hence $f(n)$ is a real number. Or would that be an incorrect statement?

Comment: For any bound $M$ you can find $n_c$ with $H_n > M, n> n_c$

Comment: Yes it is divergent, and @Math1000 has already given the asymptotic form $H_n \sim \log n$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll look for a proof on the internet.

Comment: @Vizuna Consider the upper and lower Darboux sums of $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ on $[1,n]$ (with the partition $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$).

Comment: This is interesting, didn't come across Darboux sums before. So the upper Darboux sum is $1 + \frac{1}{2} + ... + \frac{1}{n} = f(n)$ and the lower Darboux sum is $\frac{1}{2} + ... + \frac{1}{n}$ which is $f(n) - 1$. A lower bound for the upper Darboux sum is the area under the curve $\ln n$ and an upper bound for the lower Darboux sum is $\ln n$. Combining we have $\ln n \le f(n) \le \ln n + 1$. Is this enough to show that $f(n) \in \Theta(\ln n)$? The $+1$ is bugging me though... how to deal with it?

Comment: @Math1000 Forgot to tag you yesterday. How do I deal with the $+1$?

Comment: Asymptotically it is insignificant; $$\log(n+1)-\log(n) = \log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0. $$